# Create arrays of dates in CCK list

Tags: entities, datetime

I want to create a list of dates in a CCK select list with PHP arrays.

I don't have any luck with this, any help is appreciated.

Minimum date: +4 days
Maximum date: +2 months
Only bussines days (Mon-Fri)

And I also would like to display the dates in the following format: "Mon 5 Nov."

Thanks.

Comment: I've managed to create an array:

`<?php

function getDateRange($startDate, $endDate, $format="D j M") {
    $datesArray = array();
    $total_days = round(abs(strtotime($endDate) - strtotime($startDate)) / 86400, 0) + 1;
    if($days<0) { return false; }
    for($day=0; $day<$total_days; $day++)
    {
        $datesArray[] = date($format, strtotime("{$startDate} + {$day} weekdays"));
    }
    return $datesArray;}

$dateRange = getDateRange('+4 days', '+2 months');

return $dateRange;

?>`